# Retrieve Stripe account enabled payment methods

Tags: stripe-payments

The payment methods on a Stripe account are listed on the dashboard:

[image]

I need to know which payment methods are enabled on a stripe account using [java-stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java).

How to do that?

I tried [`Account.retrieve()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve?lang=java) but that didn't return the enabled payment methods.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Stripe support team, it seems impossible to know on each connected account which payment methods are available.

The best they can offer is to detect on source creation the event `payment_method_unactivated`.